# get the role and last_login from user FosuserBundle Symfony

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to get in my layout the name of role and the date of last_login .

i use Symfony 2.5, and FosuserBundle

So when i use:

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

i get the name of username, but when i use :

```
{{ app.user.roles }}
```

i get array This is quite normal since it is array.

```
  <div class="floatleft marginleft10">
                    <ul class="inline-ul floatleft">
                        <li>Espace {{ app.user.username }}</li>

                        <li><a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br />               
                    <span class="small grey">Last Login: {{ app.user.last_login }}</span>
                </div>
```

when i added {{ app.user.last_login }} i get exception :

```
       Method "last_login" for object "My\testBundle\Entity\Collaborateur" does not exist in MytestBundle::layout2.html.twig
```

any help please !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Role**

You will (as you stated) be returning an array from `app.user.roles` or `$user->getRoles()` so you should treat it like an array.

For a list..

```
<ul>
    {% for role in app.user.roles %}
        <li>{{ role }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Or comma separated..

```
{% for role in app.user.roles %}
    {{ role }}{% if false == loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Last Login**

The field is..

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $lastLogin;
```

So you should be using..

```
{{ app.user.lastLogin }}
```

And probably with the date filter..

```
{{ app.user.lastLogin|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```

Comment: yes thank you and for the role name howa can i get it??

Comment: but i get all the roles i want just the role of user connected!!

Comment: That is all of the roles of the user connected. Every user will have the role `ROLE_USER` by default, then if you add roles they will have those as well.

Comment: I suggest `app.user.roles|join(', ')`